# Help with Parsing XML in iOS

Tags: xml, ios, core-data, xml-parsing

I'm having a problem with my app, I'm attempting to save stuff in core data by copying a label, but its giving me this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'

This is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



    ClientDownload *currentClientDownload = [[xmlClientDownloadParser clientArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(45, 2, 265, 30);
    clientName = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame] autorelease];
    clientName.numberOfLines = 2;
    clientName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    clientName.text = [currentClientDownload NAME];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:clientName];

    CGRect detailFrame1 = CGRectMake(45, 40, 265, 30);
    clientMobile = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:detailFrame1] autorelease];

    CGRect detailFrame2 = CGRectMake(45, 40, 265, 30);
    clientAccount = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:detailFrame2] autorelease];

    clientAccount.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    clientAccount.text = [currentClientDownload ACCOUNT];
    clientMobile.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    clientMobile.text = [currentClientDownload MOBILE];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:clientAccount];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:clientMobile];

    NSLog(@"SaveData");
    Clients *client = (Clients *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Clients" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    if( (clientName.text) || (clientAccount.text) || (clientMobile.text) != NULL)
    {   
        client.ACCOUNT = clientAccount.text;
        client.NAME = clientName.text;
        client.MOBILE = clientMobile.text;
        NSLog(@"CLIENT GENERATED");
        NSError *error;

        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

 }
    NSError * error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Clients" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects)

    {

        NSLog(@"ACCOUNT: %@",[info valueForKey:@"ACCOUNT"]);
        NSLog(@"NAME: %@",[info valueForKey:@"NAME"]);
        NSLog(@"MOBILE: %@",[info valueForKey:@"MOBILE"]);

    }   

    [fetchRequest release];
    return cell; 

}
```

Comment: What line does the code crash on. Do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have wrong if-statement here:

`if( (clientName.text) || (clientAccount.text) || (clientMobile.text) != NULL)`

It should look like this one (if I'm not mistaken):

`if( (clientName.text != NULL) && (clientAccount.text != NULL) && (clientMobile.text != NULL))`

Comment: still giving me the error , i tried to change it around a bit , but for some reason im gettin the wait fences error too .... crap

Comment: On what line does it fails? Do you removed all app data after making changes that i suggested? Yoy should reset app data

Comment: you wanna take a look at the application ? im trying to view the generated data in another view .... its actually giving me the fences error alot now :/

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing from phone. Try to localize the problem and then fully describe it here. Ill try to help

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you are checking all three `UILabel`s for zero text at the same time. That means, if there is text in one of them and the other two are empty, the if condition will return `YES`. You then try to assign this empty text to your custom object.

You should revise your if statements to refer to each field separately. Thus:

```
if (clientAccount.text != nil)  client.ACCOUNT = clientAccount.text;
if (clientName.text != nil)     client.NAME = clientName.text;
if (clientMobile.text != nil)   client.MOBILE = clientMobile.text;
```

If this does not fix it, please post the exact line where you get the crash.

Comment: with your fix , the code doesnt even load the data through the xml parse ! if you want to take a look at the code i will be more than glad to send you the code , its rather difficult to paste 6 classes :/

Comment: Well, it seems it is in that area where your problem lies... Try setting the properties to @"" instead of leaving them at `nil`.

Comment: Also, I would not import new records and save them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This method is potentially called several times. Maybe this is where you run into trouble.